# jQury hover зацикливается

Tags: jquery, joomla, javascript

Всем привет. Вот тут делаю сайт http://maxicom.mnogomesta.ru/ (сайт на joomla 2.5) , обратите внимание на "выезжающие блоки справа" онлайн заявки. Если быстро провести мышкой по ним то анимация зацикливается и может прыгать туда сюда раз 5-10. Сделано всё на основе 2-х методов jQuery версии 1.7.1 , метод `hover(over,out)` и метод `animate()`. Вот код

```
jQuery("#apply-to").hover(
    function () { jQuery("#apply-to").animate({right:"0px"},700)}
,
    function () {jQuery("#apply-to").animate({right:"-600px"},700)}
);
```

Я просто изменяю позиционирование `Div` в котором находится вся форма при наведении и "уходе" курсора мыши с блока `Div`. Не соображу как мне зацикливание прекратить. Тут же проблема, если у вас например поле формы что-то запомнило и вместо того чтобы ввести значение вы выбираете это значение из выпадающего списка запомненных значений, фокус с `Div`-а теряется и срабатывает `out` метода `hover()`. Есть у кого мысли здравые - поделитесь. Сразу скажу `click()` не предлагать, потому как заказчик хочет именно по наведению, компонент `chronoforms` тоже тут не работает, конфликтует со скриптами. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Нужно объяснить заказчику что это называется "задрот"! Пускай попробует заполнить форму и не отвести мышку от границ этого окна))) После этого он скажет - onclick i love you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery("#apply-to").hover(
    function () { jQuery("#apply-to").stop().animate({right:"0px"},700)}
,
    function () {jQuery("#apply-to").stop().animate({right:"-600px"},700)}
);
```

А в остальном [@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan) прав.